# Overlapping Design with Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hey I am doing my first steps with the Bootstrap Grid system.

I am wondering how to create the following design with the grid system for large displays:[image: Layout]

I am confused how to create the overlapping parts using the correct syntax and the right use of the grid system.

Do you have any suggestions how to start?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there, can you be a little more clear as to which parts/colored blocks you want help with here so it is easier for people to help. Put up a Fiddle with the code you have so far, so someone does not have to start from scratch.  Are you asking about just the 2 darkblue and 1 dark green blocks here?

Comment: Well, I am asking about every overlapping part. E.G. the white one on the top, the two blue and green ones in the middle etc.. I need a an excerpt to start with to use the grid system right. I know how to do it with static html. But I do not understand how to do it in the context of the grid system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up a **[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/1zec14ko/)** to help show how you could start this.

In this code it uses a few of the col-XX-XX classes to helpfully show how these divs can change where they are and the width. Just to give you an idea. Grab the window and try resizing it to see how this works.

I gave the 2 blue and 1 green some **offset** to the right by using `col-lg-offset-6`.
On small screen size I made the width of the 2 blue and 1 green change to a equal width. You can now make these div do what you want them too.

Hope this will get you started.

```
<div class="container col-lg-12">
        <div class="row col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 block-white">
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <div class="container col-lg-12">    
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-5 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6 block-blue">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-6 block-blue">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-6 block-green">
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Awesome!!! That helps me a lot to understand how it works! Thank your very much!!!!